# Dynamic Merging Cells in SSRS (usual answer doesn't apply)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, merge

I developed a dynamic Access report using "On Format" and "On Print" Event coding, and now I want to move over to SQL and SSRS, and I was wondering if there is ANY WAY at all, to capture the functionality offered in Access + VBA in SSRS. Frankly, I think it's absurd that this level of functionality is missing.

Reason being, previously I allowed users to merge text boxes in data entry by putting a "======" next to the column they want merged across, and the code would just extend the width across the "======" fields during printing.
Specifically, I have a Report with close to 20 text-boxes in each row, and any of them could be merged any which way in any random row, depending on where the users put the "======". 
Meaning, if I would go the standard road of having many rows and just setting the visibility conditionally, I would need an enormous permutation of rows to capture all the possible merged cell layouts.

Currently, I am considering using RDCE, but I am not totally sure it will do what I need since the documentation is so scarce. Frankly, I am more wondering if there isn't some way to replicate the "on format" event coding in SSRS?

EDIT:Note, ultimately the goal would be to automatically generate their reports online, so is there some way of coding for events on the online rendering?

Comment: If anyone cares, I just went ahead and switched to ASP.NET MVC and I got it working. Anyone with my issue should just dump SSRS cause it's useless. Best way to put in superscripts is to use a dll that generates an image of the text, versus <sup> in ASP.NET